# Need some clarification about NodeJs and Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

Okay so this is maybe a very silly question and maybe not fit for stack over flow but It would help me a lot to understand that. 
So I am learning Nodejs in a tutorial...

Right now I learned about creating a server and sending back something to the client when he/she performs a request, for example typing the URL in his/her browser. So this is what I did:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,resp){
   resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   var page = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');
   resp.end(text);
});
```

also, there's other instances that the teacher uses express.js to get the request from the user like so:

```
app.get('/', function(req, resp){
   res.render('index');
});
```

ok so this maybe poor coding but you get the idea. Now, my silly question is: 
Why should I create this server and this response to the client since if I type on my browser http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html it will already load my HTML page and show me its contents? I have a live website in which I used hostgator to get my domain and host my website and I didn't need to set up a server in Nodejs to make the request to access the page.

I would be very glad if someone could explain to me why I should use that code in nodejs

Comment: For clarification -- does your HTML page load on localhost before you start the node app?

Comment: You have another web server running on your computer. If you're happy with that, then no, you probably don't need to create another.

Comment: No, the route would be `127.0.0.1:8888/`. You configured the `'/'` route, so it will match `'/'`, not `'/index.html'`.

Answer (score 2):

You would write your own server using Node.js when you want to be able to write JavaScript in order to determine **how** the server responds to a given request (e.g. to dynamically generating pages or communicate over Websockets). This would *replace* the existing HTTP server you are using.

If you are just serving up a static file, there is no point in doing anything so complex … but learning how to serve up a static file is a way to learn the very basics.

Comment: Thank you  a lot Quentin! One more thing, if I am to put a website with hostgator for example (or any other hosting company) in my back end code what port should I put in app.listen(); to open the back end server?

Comment: It depends. Deployment of Node.js server applications isn't just a matter of shoving them on to a server. There are lots of questions to consider such as "Are you exposing it directly?", "Are you using a frontend proxy?". There are long articles discussing the different ways to deploy them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends.

If you just want to render your index.html file, Node.js is overused.

You will use Node.js and routes to make a restful API, some webservice that returns data from the database and so on.